# Dealing with numbers too large for machine precision in Graphics

Tags: graphics, arbitrary-precision, machine-precision

`Graphics` only supports machine precision numbers (i.e. number that can be converted to machine precision).  Take for example

```
Graphics[Point[{0, Exp[1000.]}]]
```

which produces an error because `Exp[1000.]` is too large to be representable as a `double`.

What is the *simplest* way to deal with situations like this?  Replacing all too large numbers with just some arbitrary very large machine precision number is fine, as they'll be outside the plot range anyway.  I'm sure there must be some built-in function that can fix this easily.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I wonder whether I have understood your question correctly because I know you'll be aware of `Clip`

```
data = 
 Clip[#, {-$MaxMachineNumber, $MaxMachineNumber}] & /@ {0, Exp[1000.]}

(*
==> {0, 1.797693135*10^308}
*)

Precision /@ data

(*
==> {\[Infinity], MachinePrecision}
*)


data = RandomReal[10, {10, 2}]~Join~{{0, Exp[1000.]}};

Graphics[Point[data], PlotRange -> {0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
data = Map[Clip[#, {-$MaxMachineNumber, $MaxMachineNumber}] &, data, 2]

(*
==> {{1.712790207, 2.900090032}, {2.659619591, 
  7.829120544}, {1.961467042, 3.28800444}, {8.391594058, 
  6.895205615}, {7.272335729, 5.320941734}, {2.663140973, 
  0.988927991}, {3.408201238, 2.47708199}, {7.951584505, 
  7.102838229}, {6.826916007, 5.639933047}, {5.307337319, 
  1.629710693}, {0, 1.797693135*10^308}}
*)

Graphics[Point[data], PlotRange -> {0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 5):

Using @Sjoerd idea of Clipping, maybe you could use too `Rescale`. Something simple could be a wrapper to rescale every point inside a `Graphics`:

```
rescale[things_] := 
 Module[{points = 
    Cases[things, {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}, ∞], minmax, 
   rescaled},
  minmax = Transpose[{Min /@ #, Max /@ #} &@Transpose[points]];
  rescaled = Clip[minmax, {-$MaxMachineNumber, $MaxMachineNumber}];
  things /. 
     {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ} :>
       {Rescale[x, minmax[[1]], rescaled[[1]]], 
        Rescale[y, minmax[[2]], rescaled[[2]]]}
  ]
```

This is just a "draft" since points should be taken only from graphics directives with coordinates, and then filter also the `Scaled` or `Offset` coordinates.

```
Graphics[rescale[{... Points[data], ..., Polygon[poly], ...}]]
```

Anyway, you will have to adjust the aspect ratio after doing the rescale (the rescale is different for each axis).