# ListPlot very large numbers

Tags: plotting, numerics

Suppose we have the following function:

```
NN = 150;
W[n1_] := NN!/(n1 ! (NN - n1!)) (1/2)^n1 (1/2)^(NN - n1)
```

Then we can `Plot` or `Listplot` it:

```
ListPlot[Table[{n1, W[n1]}, {n1, 1, 10, 0.1}], Joined -> True, 
 Frame -> True, Axes -> None, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 16}, 
 PlotMarkers -> {"\[Bullet]", 10}, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

If we change `NN` to `200` or more, then we get the following error:

> ListPlot::prng: Value of option PlotRange ->
>   {{0,10.},{-1.341145999799935*10^312,2.466246209857526*10^312}} is not
>   All, Full, Automatic, a positive machine number, or an appropriate
>   list of range specifications. >>

How can we deal with these large numbers in plot?

Comment: Divide the function by some large exponent, e.g. 10^200, then generate your own tick labels that reverse the scaling.

Comment: The workaround to use is what rasher said.  One more thing to mention is that while in general Mathematica can handle arbitrary precision numbers, `Plot` (and `Graphics`) will only work with machine precision numbers, i.e. numbers smaller than `$MaxMachineNumber`.

Comment: rasher and Szabolcs, thanks a lot for your answers.

Comment: I just met the same problem. Shouldn't this be considered a bug? Because the error message that mma gives is completely irrelevant.

Comment: This problem has annoyed me for several years -I use the scaling solution but it is a nuisance. Maybe it is worth writing to Wolfram to develop a specialized function for this purpose that does this scaling automatically so the front end plot functions can be used seamlessly.

Comment: @Allan Note that I have converted your post into a comment (like this one).  This is the appropriate place for such notes.  I realize that as a new member you can only comment on your own questions but if you begin to participate in asking and/or answering questions that will quickly change.  See:  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/privileges

Comment: @YiWang I agree that the way this is handled makes it seem like a bug.  If the system was specifically designed with this limitation in mind I imagine that a different error message would be used.

Comment: Closely related, possible duplicate: [(2938)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2938/121)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Plot` and more generally `Graphics` can only handle coordinates that are machine numbers, i.e. in the range `$MinMachineNumber` to `$MaxMachineNumber`.  On my machine these are of the order $10^{308}$.

This limitation is probably present because graphics are rendered by the front end (not the kernel which supports arbitrary precision arithmetic).

The simplest solution would be to linearly rescale everything, i.e. divide the numbers by a large value, before plotting.  Then you can manually set the [`Ticks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Ticks.html) to reflect the unscaled values.

Comment: I think Plot uses Compile to plot faster, so it uses only machine number.. ?

Comment: @DaoTRINH  Good point.  I don't know if it auto-compiles or not. But it also has the WorkingPrecision option, so it *can* work with arbitrary precision arithmetic, even if it doesn't by default ...  This comes useful as a simple brute force solution when there's some cancellation in the formula that eats up precision.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, well, bug or not here is a workaround. Take the logarithm base 10 of the values, then no matter how small or large they are, you can still plot them. For example, consider this plot with some really huge values, circa $10^{1500}$, co-plotted, with some incredibly small ones $10^{-1500}$. Only problem is when the numbers are negative, but even those can be plotted with the new `ReImPlot[]` command, i.e., "Real Imaginary Plot," for the continuous case and possibly `ComplexListPlot[]`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a limitation of `Graphics` itself.  If the `PlotRange` problem is bypassed we still get an error:

```
NN = 200;
W[n1_] := NN!/(n1! (NN - n1!)) (1/2)^n1 (1/2)^(NN - n1)
dat = Table[{n1, W[n1]}, {n1, 1, 10, 0.1}];

Graphics[Point @ dat]
```

[image]

This at least indicates that the problem is with the coordinates, but again the error message is less than accurate such obviously that *is* "a pair of numbers."

Briefly searching I could not find it directly stated in the documentation that `Graphics` only works with machine size floats.  I wonder if such an omission (if true) is sufficient to consider this at least a "documentation bug."

Answer (score 1):

A workaround I found while struggling with the same problem. It seems that `Graphics` can interpret `\[Infinity]` and `-\[Infinity]`. So the idea is simply to filter the data before plotting it:

```
Which[# < 0 && Abs[#] >= $MaxMachineNumber, -\[Infinity], # > 0 && 
Abs[#] >= $MaxMachineNumber, +\[Infinity], True, #] & /@ data
```

The advantage is to not having to change the scale and the ticks of the plot.