# Errors when plotting Exp[-x]/x for large values of x

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot a very simple function `f[x_]:=Exp[-x]/x` on a log-log scale like this

```
LogLogPlot[f[x], {x, 10^(-5), 10^7}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The problem is that for large values of x the plot suddenly jumps to 1 instead of going to zero as it should. I have tried to tabulate the values and increase working precision but it doesn't go away. The problem does not appear if I use

```
LogLogPlot[Exp[-x]/x, {x, 10^(-5), 10^7}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Anyone can explain me what is happening?

Comment: Hey I edited to format your code. In the future, you can format code on your own by selecting the code block and pressing ctrl+k

Comment: There are some weird things going on here.  What version of Mathematica are you using?  8, 9 or 10 for the Raspberry Pi?  They give different results.  Normally I'd say, just use `WorkingPrecision -> 20` if you're getting runaway errors from machine precision.  But in this case using that option in v9 gives incorrect results.

Comment: Yep, I was halfway editing my comment to suggest changing the `WorkingPrecision`. Then I tried it and, in v9 on OSX at least, it goes to 1 regardless how high `WorkingPrecision` is.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I am using mathematica 9 on mac, have tried all kinds of working precision but still doesn't work. I would first like to understand what the problem is...

Comment: one more thing, if I were to plot directly the function Exp[-x]/x, so without difining f first, then it works perfectly. But the function has more parameters etc so I can't leave it like that. What to do?

Comment: I would file a bug report to WR...

Comment: @gpap that would be terrible, my project is now compromised...

Comment: @mia Try evaluating your function: `LogLogPlot[Evaluate@f[x], {x, 10^(-5), 10^7}]`

Comment: Another log plot related bug: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15628/  Perhaps the fix there might help here.

Comment: The error seems to happen when `f[x]` exceeds `$MinMachineNumber`.  See also http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/42093  Setting `SetSystemOptions["CatchMachineUnderflow" -> False]` fixes the plot (but creates other problems).  There's a safer way, but I don't have time right now to answer.

Answer (score 5):

This appears to be some sort of bug in `LogLogPlot`. Note that you can always compute the function at specific values of x as in most other procedural languages and use one of the `List*Plot` functions:

```
With[{x = 10^Range[-5, 7, 0.01]},
    ListLogLogPlot[Transpose@{x, f[x]}, Joined -> True, 
        PlotRange -> {{1*^-5, 1*^7}, {1*^-9, 1*^6}}]]
```

[image]

The only drawback here is that you won't have the benefit of the adaptive sampling in `Plot`-like functions, but a lot of the time you can live without it.

Answer (score 5):

Or since:

$$e^x=1+\frac{2}{-\coth \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-1}$$

```
f[x_] := (1 + (2/(-1 - Coth[x/2])))/x
LogLogPlot[f[x], {x, 10^(-5), 10^7}]
```

[image]

Also, by using *Mathematica* you can find that

```
ExpToTrig[Exp[-x]]
(* => Cosh[x] - Sinh[x] *)
```

Thus using

```
f[x_] := (Cosh[x] - Sinh[x])/x
```

produces the same Plot.

Comment: Well.., the bug appears with plotting `Exp[-x]` as well. If the actual `f[x]` has `Exp[-x]` it is still possible to use the equivalence. (I guess?)

Comment: One can define `mexp[x_]:=(1 + (2/(-1 + Coth[-x/2])))` and use it instead of `Exp[-x]` everywhere (since `Exp[-x]` seems to be the issue).

Comment: Thank you, you are very creative, I would have never thought about writing the exponential like that :)

Comment: @mia, I edited so _Mathematica_ thinks for you :)

Comment: I would have thought that cosh-sinh would lead to same strange behavior but apparently it works with that as well :). thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Just to show LogLogPlot is getting the correct values:

```
 f[x_] := Exp[-x]/x
 ListLogLogPlot[
     Sort[Reap[
          LogLogPlot[fx=f[x], {x, 10^(-5), 10^7}, 
              EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x, fx}]]][[2, 1]]], 
              Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Of course setting a sensible plot range in ListLogLogPlot gives the expected result.

```
 ListLogLogPlot[
   Sort[Reap[
     LogLogPlot[fx = f[x], {x, 10^(-5), 10^7}, 
          EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x, fx}]]][[2, 1]]], Joined -> True, 
          PlotMarkers -> Graphics[Point[{0, 0}]], PlotRange -> {10^-8, 10^7}]
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure that `10^-3619123` is the correct value.. Or maybe I don't get it :)

Comment: `Exp[-10^7]/10^7 // N` -> O(10^-4342952).  I honestly don't know what it should be...

Comment: It should be reported as a serious bug I guess :)

Comment: Just for fun your formula gives the same thing if I request 10 million digits (!) precision on the `Coth` ..

Comment: or breaking out the pencil and paper :  `10^(-10^7 Log[10, E] - 7) // N` -> 1.516 10^-4342952

Comment: Mathics.net gives the same as well and so does WolframAlpha. MATLAB is right.. :D